# ng build hangs in VSTS

Tags: angular, azure-devops, angular-cli, azure-pipelines-build-task, angular-cli-v6

I'm using following build command in VSTS to build my angular 6 project in VSTS

```
ng build --prod --base-href /myproject/ --no-progress --build-optimizer=false
```

Builds hangs in 90% and not getting completed. 
The same command working fine in local machine.

Helps much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the same `CLI` version both in your local and your VSTS?

Comment: @DavidR Yes, I have verified that.

Comment: Can you try without no-progress and check when it hangs?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I tried ng build --prod alone also. Its hangs in the middle way.

Comment: Can you share the logs?

Comment: Is the Node version different between your local environment and the hosted agent?

Comment: @Calidus both are same latest version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried the following command, its working fine.
Looks like memory allocation problem only

```
node --max_old_space_size=102400 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
```